# Any alternatives to the Stern-Gerlach experiment I could do at home (or school)?

Tags: home-experiment

I am running a bridging class for alevel students who want to go into physics at university and I think it would be really nice to show the Stern-Gerlach experiment, showing both the quantisation of spin and the change of results when we measure the orientation.

Comment: [Phet Stern Gerlach simulation](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/stern-gerlach/stern-gerlach_en.html) and if you sign in youi can download teachers'notes.